# Como retirar um elemento de textarea

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse textarea:

```
<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea>
```

Como posso fazer para remover o **display: none;** com javascript? Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").style.display = "block" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode remover o `display` simplesmente atribuindo a ele um valor vazio:

```
document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").style.display = "";
```

Com `display = "block"` você não estará removendo, mas sim apenas alterando o valor de `none` para `block`, embora ambos os valores fazem com que o elemento fique visível.